# Два и более сетевых соединения одновременно

Tags: сеть, lan

Работает по схеме 1 или 2, при включеном eth0 не работает мобильное соединение, NetworkManager показывает, что оно активно, однако его просто не удается пропиногвать, не говоря о чем-то большем, при отключении eth0 мобильное соединение тут же подымается и работает, однако очень хочется сделать вариант №3 и заставить два подключения работать одновременно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сервер под CentOS 6.5

Comment: Смотрите в сторону маркировки пакетов с помощью `iptables` и множественных таблиц маршрутизации. С дефолтными настройками многошлюзовые конфигурации работают отвратительно.

Comment: А как поможет таблица маршрутизации? Маршрут от PPP к Eth заставит пакеты мобильного трафика улетать через сетевой интерфейс, а мне надо их обрабатывать и совершать вызов через GSM-шлюз, нужно добиться работы двух интерфейсов одновременно

Comment: Не будет маршрута от `ppp` к `eth`. Будет две таблицы. Одна привязывается к интерфейсу `ppp0`, другая - к `eth0`. Таблицы независимые, определение принадлежности к таблице - на основе меток `iptables`, которые он ставит на пакетах, основываясь на интерфейсе-получателе пакета. После таких манипуляций фактически создаются две сетевых области, трафик между которыми ходить не может и сервер корректно работает с несколькими интернет-подключениями. P.S. Впрочем, если Вы уверены, что Вам это не поможет - не используйте, никто не заставляет.

Comment: Да я не "уверен, что не поможет", а просто не понял принципа, думал таблица форвардинг наладит между интерфейсами ввиду не знания матчасти, щас когда вы разьяснили про две таблицы и сетевые области стало ясно, спасибо)

Comment: Кстате если WAN отрубить то схема 3 работает, то есть в eth0 в разделе gateway ставлю 0.0.0.0, все работает, интернета через кабель правда нету, но все таки есть прогресс, однако мне не понятно, трафик через eth0 никуда не делся, а работа обоих интерфейсов наладилась, почему?

Comment: Потому что при отсутствии WAN роутер кинет серверу ICMP-ответ "Destination Unreachable" и сервер перенаправит пакет на другой шлюз.

Comment: Аааааааа, ну точно, спасибо)